# Испанский словарь для Postgres

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Подскажите, где найти испанский словарь для настройки полнотекстового поиска на Postgre? Если у кого есть актуальная ссылка, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: Какая у вас ОС?  На *Deban* или *Ubuntu*, вроде, достаточно `sudo apt install hunspell-es`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел испанский словарь тут - https://github.com/sbosio/rla-es